# Há forma de uma entidade pertencer a um usuário no hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou procurando uma forma simplificada de vincular uma entidade de banco a um usuário especifico, quem cadastrou, de tal forma que não precise setar o campo na hora do cadastro. Há alguma forma simplificada de fazer isto?

O maior problema de se colocar uma chave estranjeira é que depois precisa-se reescrever as querys para que a consulta leve em conta o usuario logado.

Exemplo:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM produto where p.userid = ?1",
            countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM produto")
Page<Produto> findAll(long userid, Pageable pageable);
```

O que torna difícil o funcionamento porque para cada entidade nova que crie preciso reescrever o mesmo.

Comment: Forma mais simples do que criar uma FK não nula em tal entidade representando o usuário? Acho que não tem.

Comment: O grande X da questão neste caso é que quando fazemos uma consulta é preciso reescrever as query de consulta de tal forma que verifiquem se a id do usuário logado com jwt token é a mesma do usuário que cadastrou.

Comment: Olhe o que editei e coloquei acima.

Comment: Entendo. Mas não vejo solução adequada para seu problema. Você pode tentar uma chave primaria dupla, mas isso levaria para partes fora do meu conhecimento. Ou uma chave de código que combine um sequencial e o usuario, e você montaria essa chave no programa.

Comment: Mas o ideal seria atribuir uma chave estrangeira mesmo. Não há sentido em não fazer dessa forma. É a mesma ideia de cortar o ferro da cerca enquanto ela está sem cadeado.

Comment: Uma outra possível solução é ver se é viável criar uma sobrecarga no interpretador do Hibernate, que faria a verificação pelo usuário, seja lá qual usuário você tenha em mente. Ai, os seus repositórios não ficariam encarregados de saber qual usuário que é, mas você teria que fazer algo a respeito.

Comment: Não tem como fazer milagres, se esses milagres não estão com suas informações nas tabelas do banco, (in)felizmente.